# Why is Refresh Token not being sent to server as http cookie?

Tags: reactjs, express, jwt, mern, refresh-token

My app is not sending a refreshToken cookie when I try to create a product in my request.

First, when I log in, my refreshToken is set as a cookie which I'm able to see in the Application part of developer tools.

```
export const login = async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const { email, password } = req.body;
      const user = await User.findOne({ email: email });
      console.log(user);
      if (!user) return res.status(400).json({ msg: "User does not exist. " });

  
      const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
      if (!isMatch) return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Invalid credentials. " });

    let accessToken, refreshToken;
    try {
      accessToken = jwt.sign(
        { userId: user._id, email: user.email },
        process.env.JWT_SECRET,
        { expiresIn: "2m" }
      );
      refreshToken = jwt.sign(
        { userId: user._id },
        process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET,
        { expiresIn: "7d" }
      );
      const SetCookie = res.cookie("refreshToken", refreshToken, {
      httpOnly: true,
      expires: new Date(Date.now() + 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000), // 7 days
    })
    console.log(SetCookie)
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      res
        .status(500)
        .json({ message: "Signing up failed, please try again later." });    
    }
      res.status(200).json({  message: "logged in!", user, accessToken, refreshToken });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
    }
}
```

Then, I wait for my jwt token to expire in order to test if my refreshToken works when creating a product.
Here is the asyncThunk that sets the config, withCredentials:true that allows axios to send cookies to my server.

```
export const addProduct = createAsyncThunk(
  'product/addProduct',
  async (productData, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const { user, token, formData } = productData;
      const url = `http://localhost:3005/product/${user._id}/add-product`;

      const config = {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
        withCredentials: true,
      };

      const response = await axios.post(url, formData, config,);
      console.log(response);
      const newProduct = response.data.product;

      return newProduct;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      console.error(error?.response?.data ?? error.message);

      return rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
    }
  }
);
```

However the error occurs and says authentication failed because jwt token expired. This error is coming from the checkAuth function that handles the authentication for protected routes. The problem is that req.cookies.refreshToken is undefined when I tried console logging it outside of my if statement. Which means cookies aren't being sent to the backend.
Here is checkAuth code:

```
export const checkAuth = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;
    if (!authHeader) {
      throw new Error("Authentication failed!");
    }

    const token = authHeader.split(" ")[1]; // Authorization: Bearer <token>

    const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
    req.userData = { userId: decodedToken.userId };

    console.log(`DecodedToken Time : ${decodedToken.exp}`) 
    console.log(`Start, ${token}, end`)   

    const currentTime = Date.now() / 1000; // convert to seconds
    // const currentTime = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000); // convert to seconds
    if (decodedToken.exp - currentTime < 60) {
      const rToke = req.headers.cookie
      const refreshToken = rToke.split('=')[1];
      console.log(`refreshToken:${refreshToken}`)
      // Access token has expired, try to refresh using refresh token
      // console.log(refreshToken)
      if (!refreshToken) {
        throw new Error("Refresh token not found!");
      }
      try {
        const decodedRefreshToken = jwt.verify(
          refreshToken,
          process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET
        );
        console.log(decodedRefreshToken, 'refresh token was verified!')
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
      }
      
      // Validate the user from the decodedRefreshToken if necessary

      // Generate a new access token and refresh token
      const newAccessToken = jwt.sign(
        { userId: decodedToken.userId },
        process.env.JWT_SECRET,
        { expiresIn: "3m" }
      );
      const newRefreshToken = jwt.sign(
        { userId: decodedToken.userId },
        process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET,
        { expiresIn: "7d" }
      );
      res.cookie("refreshToken", newRefreshToken, { httpOnly: true });

      // Send the new access token in the response headers
      console.log(newAccessToken)
      res.set("Authorization", `Bearer ${newAccessToken}`);
      // res.json({newAccessToken})
    } else {
      const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

    }

    next();
  } catch (err) {
    const error = new HttpError('Authentication failed', 401);
    return next(error);
  }
};
```

What's more perplexing is that I have configured my server to accept cookies as well as cross origin requests.
here is code from index.js from server:

```
app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
  credentials: true,
  cookie: {
    domain: 'localhost',
  },
}));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  res.setHeader(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
  );
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PATCH, OPTIONS, DELETE');

  next();
});

app.use(cookieParser());
```

So why isn't refreshToken being sent as a cookie to my backend? The cookie's path is set to "/" and the domain is set to "localhost". Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Make sure your request that initially sets the cookie also has `withCredentials: true`

Comment: did you figure this out? I am using fetch and I am unable to send the cookies to my .net code api. frontend and backend have different domains so cross site related.

Answer (score 0):

As long as I know, refresh token is only working with https cookie.
Try to change it to https protocol. It does work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).